# How to customize or templating bbpress?

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I want to customize bbpress as my own style for example in woo-commerce plugin copy template folder/file to theme folder and it can be edit but in bbpress what is the procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the template files you want to customize out of:

```
wp-content/plugins/bbpress/templates/default/bbpress/
```

and drop them in…

```
wp-content/themes/YOUR_ACTIVE_THEME/bbpress/
```

Enjoy